# Error creating bean Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I have a java application (maven project) that has a parent root.
the application have a dependencies in other projects under root and when this application initialize the context an error is thrown:

```
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Created object org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl@173728231 to manage classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'retriableOperationExecutor' defined in file [C:\evergreen\lt-pcqc\app\Backend\Common\lab-common\target\classes\Spring\qcext-pclab-retriable-operation-executor-context.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at com.hp.alm.lab.common.spring.SpringContextLoader.loadContext(SpringContextLoader.java:44)
```

an xml file is beeing loaded and from some reason don't find its relevant constructor although it is located in the same jar that holds the xml file.

other project that holds a dependency to the same project is running on a jetty server without any exceptions.
here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="retriableOperationExecutor" class="com.hp.alm.lab.common.utils.RetriableOperationExecutor" scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg name="Default_Count" index="0" type="int" value="${default_count:5}"/>
        <constructor-arg name="Initial_Sleep_Millis" index="1" type="int" value="${initial_sleep_millis:2000}"/>
        <constructor-arg name="Max_Sleep_Time" index="2" type="int" value="${max_sleep_time:30000}"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and the relevant constructor is:

```
public class RetriableOperationExecutor {


    private static int DEFAULT_COUNT;
    private static int INITIAL_SLEEP_MILLIS;
    private static  int MAX_SLEEP_TIME;

    public RetriableOperationExecutor(int Default_Count,int Initial_Sleep_Millis,int Max_Sleep_Time) {
        DEFAULT_COUNT=Default_Count;
        INITIAL_SLEEP_MILLIS=Initial_Sleep_Millis;
        MAX_SLEEP_TIME=Max_Sleep_Time;
    }

    public RetriableOperationExecutor() {}
```

I did try to add the index, name, in the constructor-arg but without any luck.

any idea?

Comment: A constructor that initializes static variables (common to all instances) does not seem right to me, why not a static method instead? Or maybe you want immutable fields, but different for every instance? In that case use `final` instead of `static` keyword.

Comment: there is a static execute method that using those fields. this constructor exist because I want to receive the values from properties file, and when I use property in the xml instead of constructor-arg the fields where empty in runtime.

Comment: I've never used this kind of config file (Spring, I imagine) but something tells me it's looking for setters/getters when you use `<properties>`, maybe that was your problem. Also, why would you use a static method on something you declare a singleton? But that's another debate of course, I'll stop polluting this thread.